# vb.net: VolumeSerialNumber vs. vb6 GetVolumeInformation

Tags: vb.net

In VB6 I am getting the serial number of a volume like this:

```
Temp1 = String$(255, Chr$(0))
Temp2 = String$(255, Chr$(0))
r = GetVolumeInformation(uDrive, Temp1, StrLen(Temp1), lSerialNumber, 0, 0, Temp2, StrLen(Temp2))

GetPartitionSerialNumber = lSerialNumber
```

In VB.NET I use

```
    Dim disk As System.Management.ManagementObject = New System.Management.ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + uDrive + ":""")
    disk.Get()
    Dim SerialNumber As String = disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
```

VB6 returns -1870518177, but VB.NET returns 9082285F.

Can somebody tell me what I need to do to also get the result -1870518177 in .NET?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `Val("&H" & ...)` will work, it's the old VB6 way of doing things which isn't optimal.  The better way to do it would be:

```
Dim iSerial As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(sSerialNumber, 16)
```

The `16` parameter specifies the base (hexidecimal is base 16).

Answer (score 0):

Dim iSerial As Integer = Val("&H" & sSerialNumber)